# C++: gcc/g++ compiler error logf is not a member of std

Tags: c++

I have written a C++ file which contains a function which uses `std::logf()`. It contains this line

```
float xx = std::logf(x) - 1.0f;
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
math_functions.cpp: In function ‘int fclamp_log_to_int(float, int, int)’:
math_functions.cpp:49:21: error: ‘logf’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘logb’?
   49 |     float xx = std::logf(x) - 1.0f;
      |                     ^~~~
      |                     logb
```

I have included the `cmath` header, which is required according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log

My g++ version is

```
g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
```

and I have included the flag `-std=c++11` in my `Makefile`.

Changing `logf` to `log` compiles without issue.

Is this a `gcc` problem?

Comment: What did you `#include` to import it? Just `cmath`? Are you in C++11 mode or better?

Comment: @tadman Here's a MCVE: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8fo9ooz8M

Comment: Works fine in `clang` for me, so not sure what's up with that online compiler.

Comment: @tadman It starts working in Clang if I add `-stdlib=libc++`, so presumably a libstdc++ bug.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not sure that's a bug so much as a requirement for using it?

Comment: @tadman Not sure I understand. libstdc++ fails to provide a function, isn't it a bug then?

Comment: It compiles fine for me with `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wno-c++11-extensions -lstdc++` options.

Comment: @tadman libstdc++ and libc++ are different implementations of the C++ standard library. One is provided by GCC, and the other is provided by Clang. Clang can use one or the other, depending on the flags. One is bugged in this regard, the other is not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, I see what you're saying. That is peculiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a gcc problem?

Yes. And it is [reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700). To be fair, it was somewhat unclear whether `std::logf` was required to exist due to an editorial mistake which caused a contradiction in the standard that was [fixed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0175r1.html) in C++17.

You can work around it by using `std::log(float)` instead. Another workaround is to use `::logf`, although that isn't necessary since you can use `std::log(float)`.